# How to decode array containing json with Circe

Tags: json, scala, circe, http4s-circe, circe-optics

I have my circe Decoder as shown below. I am confident my Sentiment Decoder works correctly so won't include it below.

```
case class CryptoData(value: String, valueClassification: Sentiment)
```

```
  implicit val decoder: Decoder[CryptoData] = Decoder.instance { json =>
    for {
      value               <- json.downField("data").get[String]("value")
      valueClassification <- json.downField("data").get[Sentiment]("value_classification")
    } yield CryptoData(value, valueClassification)
  }
```

my Json looks like this

```
{
  "name" : "Fear and Greed Index",
  "data" : [
    {
      "value" : "31",
      "value_classification" : "Fear",
      "timestamp" : "1631318400",
      "time_until_update" : "54330"
    }
  ],
  "metadata" : {
    "error" : null
  }
}
```

I simply want `value` and `value_classification`. As can be seen, those values sit within an array.

I suspect Circe is looking to decode a `List[data]` but I don't want to create a `case class DataInfo(list: List[Data])` it just doesn't feel right.

Comment: Well, you have an array in the JSON, even if it's always filled with a single value you have to handle the array in Scala at some point. Parse as array and retrieve only first item for instance..

Comment: Maybe `downArray` is the thing you are looking for. You didn't say what's the problem with your decoder. Does it result in an empty set or an error?

Comment: @GaëlJ and @micaJIS thanks for the responses. I am just not sure the cleanest way to handle the "data". Do I create another case class? What would the decoder look like?
```
Invalid message body: Could not decode JSON: {
  "name" : "Fear and Greed Index",
  "data" : [
    {
      "value" : "31",
      "value_classification" : "Fear",
      "timestamp" : "1631318400",
      "time_until_update" : "51165"
    }
  ],
  "metadata" : {
    "error" : null
  }
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just missed a `downArray` call to parse `data` as the array of objects. Working decoder:

```scala
implicit val cryptoDecoder: Decoder[CryptoData] = Decoder.instance { json =>
  val data = json.downField("data").downArray
  for {
    value <- data.get[String]("value")
    valueClassification <- data.get[Sentiment]("value_classification")
  } yield CryptoData(value, valueClassification)
}
```

---

Small recomendataion:

I would advise you to define a basic decoder for `CryptoData`, it should just decode `CryptoData` from the `data` object:

```js
{
    "value" : "31",
    "value_classification" : "Fear",
    "timestamp" : "1631318400",
    "time_until_update" : "54330"
}
```

to:

```scala
CryptoData("31", Fear)
```

and if you have some extended JSON, you can just move down to the actual `CryptoData` field using some custom parser and parse object.

full code:

```scala
import io.circe
import io.circe.Decoder
import io.circe.parser._

trait Sentiment

object Sentiment {
  case object Fear extends Sentiment

  implicit val sentimentDecoder: Decoder[Sentiment] = Decoder.decodeString.map {
    case "Fear" => Fear
  }
}

case class CryptoData(value: String, valueClassification: Sentiment)

object CryptoData {
  implicit val cryptoDecoder: Decoder[CryptoData] = Decoder.instance { json =>
    for {
      value <- json.downField("value").as[String]
      valueClassification <- json.downField("value_classification").as[Sentiment]
    } yield CryptoData(value, valueClassification)
  }

  def decodeRaw(extendedObject: String): Either[circe.Error, Array[CryptoData]] =
    parse(extendedObject).flatMap(json => json.hcursor.downField("data").as[Array[CryptoData]])
}
```

testing:

```scala
val extendedJson =
  """
    |{
    |  "name" : "Fear and Greed Index",
    |  "data" : [
    |    {
    |      "value" : "31",
    |      "value_classification" : "Fear",
    |      "timestamp" : "1631318400",
    |      "time_until_update" : "54330"
    |    }
    |  ],
    |  "metadata" : {
    |    "error" : null
    |  }
    |}
    |""".stripMargin

// here should be Array
val result: Either[circe.Error, Array[CryptoData]] = CryptoData.decodeRaw(extendedJson)
// Right(CryptoData(31,Fear))
println(result.map(_.mkString(", ")))


val cryptoDataJson =
  """
    |{
    |      "value" : "31",
    |      "value_classification" : "Fear",
    |      "timestamp" : "1631318400",
    |      "time_until_update" : "54330"
    |    }
    |""".stripMargin

// Right(CryptoData(31,Fear))
println(decode[CryptoData](cryptoDataJson))
```